# Annotation on the map problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I am trying to create a map app where the user can tag a map with a photo, comment or video, but I am having a problem putting an annotation on the map.

My scenario is like this:

On the 1st page, the user can see three button with the map (1.photo, 2.comment and 3.video). When he wants to tag the map by clicking on the photo button. I use cammerView class, which gives three more buttons (1.take photo, 2.choose photo and 3.use photo); after taking a photo he has a choice of using photo or not. If he wants use this photo the screen must move to the map page, and the annotation must drop.

I am getting problem. I cannot figure out how to drop the annotation on user's map at the current location. This annotation must drop after the clicking the use button which on the photo class.

I also tried [this sample application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746), but in my case I need to have the annotation drop on the map from a button that is on the same page.  How can I make this work?

Comment: Have You tried this delegate:
`- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{}`

Comment: Yes try this but I need the annotation must drop after the click of use photo which on the next page .thank you

Comment: Then you need to code with trick, and nothing else, although I myself have implemented that, but it's tricky and complicated to explain. :(

Comment: Dupe of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713821/mkmapview-animatedrop ?

Comment: Just Google around a bit .. lots of examples to learn from; e.g.: http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial

Comment: @user6271 - just for info; writing "Then send me example code to solve this I need this very desperately" turns off a lot of people from wanting to help you.

Comment: can i ask same question again in different way with sample code

Comment: please check it out this link where i have my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421613/annotation-is-not-getting-drop-on-the-map

Comment: @ajay - Why did you delete the question with more detail?

Comment: @abiizen none give responses to that question that's why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code from Class1.m (Where Your button is touched):

### #Class1.m

```
- (void) trackImageOnMapButtonTouched
{
    MapView *tempView =[[MapView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.moveToMapView=tempView;
    [tempView release];
    int iId=[mainSlideShowImageView tag];
    self.moveToMapView.fromFlag_imageId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",iId];
    self.moveToMapView.slideShowView_imageOnSlide=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[mainSlideShowImageView tag]];
    NSLog(@"self.moveToMapView.slideShowView_imageOnSlide=%@",self.moveToMapView.slideShowView_imageOnSlide);
    [self.view addSubview:moveToMapView.view];
}
```

### #Class2.m

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    self.lattitudeArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.longitudeArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

    span.latitudeDelta=2.0;
    span.longitudeDelta=2.0;
    location.latitude=43.25f;
    location.longitude=11.00f;
    region.span=span;
    region.center=location;


    addAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithLocation:location withTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tuscany"] withSubTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Italy"] withImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]];
    addAnnotation.mTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tuscany"];
    addAnnotation.mSubTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Italy"];
    [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;   // also MKMapTypeSatellite or MKMapTypeHybrid
}


- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{

    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);


    NSString *imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",self.fromFlag_imageId];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullImgNm=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString:imageName]];
    UIImage *actualImage=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullImgNm];

    CGSize annImgSize;
    annImgSize.width=60;
    annImgSize.height=30;
    UIImage *locationImage=[self resizeImage:actualImage withSize:annImgSize];
    [rightButton setImage:locationImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(annotationPinClicked:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    annView.leftCalloutAccessoryView=rightButton;
    return annView;
}
```

And here last Supportive Class:

### .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface MapViewAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *mTitle;
    NSString *mSubTitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mSubTitle;
-(id)initWithLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location withTitle:(NSString *)title withSubTitle:(NSString *)subTitle withImage:(UIImage *)locationImage;
//- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)initWithLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) location;


@end
```

### .m:

```
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"

@implementation MapViewAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize mTitle,mSubTitle;

-(id)initWithLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location withTitle:(NSString *)title withSubTitle:(NSString *)subTitle withImage:(UIImage *)locationImage
{
    coordinate.latitude = location.latitude;
    coordinate.longitude = location.longitude;
    return self;
}

-(NSString *)title
{
    return mTitle;
}

-(NSString *)subtitle
{
    return mSubTitle;
}

- (void) dealloc{
    [mTitle release];
    [mSubTitle release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: You do know, you can use `@synthesize title=mTitle, subtitle=mSubTitle;` and then you don't have to explicitly define the `title` and `subtitle` accessors.

Comment: @Abizern: Thanks to let me know..(I didn't) :)

Comment: can i ask same question again in different way with sample code for better understanding what i am doing And what i want do?

Comment: please check it out this question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421613/annotation-is-not-getting-drop-on-the-map

Comment: @rptwsthi what is the moveToMapView over here

Comment: class2(MapView)'s object.. actually I was using that to navigate from class one to class 2, that's why i named it so, :D

Comment: B@rptwsthi where should i write this - (void) trackImageOnMapButtonTouched

Comment: @rptwsthi can write this in to my Map class

Comment: ammm, you can write it in class, in which you are clicking in button to open map view

Comment: @rptwsthi Map view already open on this i have button when click this button it goes to the photo class at three he has the another button for annotation and when user click on that button at that  time user must go previous mapview And then only annotation is droped this annotation must come after clicking button which  on that photo class

Comment: So the flow is: mapView -> photoClass -> mapView, am i right?

Comment: @rptwsthi YES flow is like that

Comment: well then when you are in photoClass, you can right the specified code over there?

Comment: Hey have you deleted your that question in which you have posted your code?

Comment: Let's sort your problem out, come into chat room iPhone/iPad

Comment: @rptwsthi Hello Yes delete the post because no one give responseson that question   .You need that.

Comment: @Ajay: have you got your solution or not? (I tried your question to go through your code)

Comment: @rptwsthi no didn't get the soluation

Comment: @rptwsthi, I need your help regarding custom annotation & callout. Can you please help me out?

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh Sure.. what is it about!