# iphone passing annotation to array

Tags: iphone, annotations

I am trying to pass custom annotation to a NSMutableArra in order to use it to populate a table view.
The code is:

in .h I define a     `NSMutableArray *mapViewAnnotations;`

then in the .m

```
- (void)plotBarPosition:(NSString *)datos{

/*
code that extract data froma a json string
*/
    MyLocation *nota =[[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:barNamePlusDistance coordinate:coordinate horario:horario oferta:offerta more:info];        
                NSLog(@"nota    :%@",nota);

            [_mapView addAnnotation:nota];   //annotation are  plot on  the map

            [mapViewAnnotations addObject:nota];   

            NSLog(@"mapViewAnnotations:%@",mapViewAnnotations);  //NSlog return null
    }
```

mapViewAnnotations results null. Perarps It is not possible to copy MyLocation object into a mutablearray?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you've never initialized your NSMutableArray.It has a null value by default.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410798/annotation-on-the-map-problem/6411217#6411217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this first in viewDidLoad or other method to init the array.

```
_mapViewAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: You are right. Now I get something like that :   ( "<MyLocation: 0xa6a2d50>","<MyLocation: 0x1eb68520>","<MyLocation: 0xa633cb0>"
)    Can i use it to fill a table?

Comment: Correct, you can now access the objects in the array using MyLocation *nota = [_mapViewAnnotations objectAtIndex:0]; // Or the appropriate index.