# How to animate marker when it is added to map on IPhone?

Tags: ios

I want to add bouncing animation for map markers when they are added to map. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think all we can do is to have an animated gif as the custom marker.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would read up on how to use the `MKAnnotation` protocol, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878758/iphone-create-mkannotation). Then, you can look at this question, which looks to very close to what you're asking about: [MKMapView: animate drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713821/mkmapview-animatedrop)

Good luck!

Comment: I think Alexey is asking about bouncing the marker and not about the drop animation